# Json.Net - Partial Deserialization with Anonymous Types

Tags: json.net

After briefly examining this [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs), it seems that Json.Net's `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType` method parses the entire JSON input from beginning to end, even if the specified anonymous type only has a single property that matches at the beginning of the input, and even if the input is 5GB long (to exaggerate the problem).

Furthermore, the [CheckAdditionalContent](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_CheckAdditionalContent.htm) property seems to only apply to content that appears after the object ends; i.e., bad JSON syntax and/or unexpected data.

I did not find a setting that will cause a partial read; i.e., stop reading when all of the properties have been discovered in the input.

To be clear, I'm expecting a behavior similar to [this partial deserialization example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm) to be the default when specifying an anonymous type.

The reasons for this are simple:

1. I have no control over the source of the JSON in my service (it comes from a third-party).
2. The content is typically 100 times larger than what I actually need from it (e.g., I need to read only 1 property, but there's 100 properties in the content).
3. Performance is the most important factor to me. I understand that the worst-case performance is still similar to reading the entire object, but in many cases you can be quite confident that you won't be reading most of the object; e.g., if I only need to read an ID property, and in every JSON input that my service receives, the ID property is the first one in the object!

Of course, the obvious alternative is to not use the Anonymous Type overload; however, I'm asking this question because it's about EXPECTED behavior. And anyway, I greatly prefer this method over the alternatives, syntactically speaking.

Am I wrong, or does Json.Net in fact always deserialize the entire input when specifying an anonymous type as the contract?